# Select where x in multi column subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Want to Select where the results are in a specific column of a subquery, how do I specify the column the IN should check from?

```
Select x from foo 
where x  in (Select y, Max(z) as MaxEntry
From bar 
Group By y)
```

say I'm selecting from this:

```
   Y                Z
   1                2
   1                4
   2                7
   2                8
```

I want to see if x is in the 4 or 8 set of the Data

Comment: there is no point selecting `y` in the sub-query. just select `x`. If you need more, please be more specific in the question.

Comment: updated to show more detail as to why

Comment: Do you care about y or max(z)?

Comment: It does not matter how complex your inner query is.  What are you actually trying to select?  You may want to provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: i care about max z

Comment: Then do **not** select `y`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the `y`, then, in the `select`.  Is the editor insisting that you need it if you're going to group by it?

Comment: @AnnL. That was it I didn't realize I could group by without specifying first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only check x column then you can write like this.

```
Select x from foo 
where x  in (Select x from bar where blah)
```

but if you want to check x and y then you can write like this.

```
Select x from foo 
where exists(Select * from bar where bar.x = foo.x and bar.y = foo.y )
```

for your query, you don't need to write y at the select

```
Select x from foo 
where x  in (Select Max(z) as MaxEntry
From bar 
Group By y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT x
FROM foo
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM bar
 GROUP BY y
 HAVING MAX(bar.z) = foo.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then this should work:

```
Select x from foo 
join (Select y, Max(z) as MaxEntry
     From bar 
     Group By y) 
as m on m.MaxEntry = x
```